# Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart PyCharm

Tags: permissions

I have this error in [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE:

`Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart PyCharm`

[image]

I have installed it form software app of Ubuntu like this:

[image]

Also i have tried to run [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) as root user to have control on the [robotux](https://abatzill.de/cms/index.php/Robotux) app, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530082/running-pycharm-as-root-from-launcher) instruction by this part:

[image: pyth]

So before of doing that instruction i have not this error problem :

`Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart PyCharm`

Now what do you thin is the reason of this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just got this problems.
My solution is deleting the current Pycharm and reinstall a new version. Then it works.